Build tensorflow 2.9.0 without cudnn
I want to build TensorFlow 2.9.0 without cudnn. In previous versions, a variable "export TF_USE_CUDNN=0" was used to disable cudnn. However, according to the release.md file, this variable is removed. Is there any suggestion?
